# Overwrite * and ** unpacking with datamodel methods?

Tags: python, python-datamodel

I'm trying to figure out how to give an object the ability to unpack values.

The use case I came up with is the following:

- Let's have an *Interval* class, which we'll use to evaluate real valued functions.
- We would like to ask for

  - Membership, hence `__contains__`.
  - Iterate over it, by calling with an specific step, or just using a default step, hence the `__call__`, and `__iter__`.
- In the future I'll support union, and intersection.

One of the features I'm looking for, is to be able to call an Interval object and unpack it, such that if `I = Interval(1, 2)` and `a, b = *I` then `a == 1` and `b == 2`.

This is mainly to work in *functions* that will have *interval limits* in their *arguments*.

For example a function `def Integrate(f, a, b): ...` and then we evaluate, `integral = Integrate(f, *I)` where $f$ real valued function and `I` is the interval we were discussing.

The problem is that I'm not entirely sure which data model method should I use.

So far the example class I came up with is the following.

```py
class Interval:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        if a >= b:
            raise Exception("Invalid values for an interval")
        self.upper = b
        self.lower = a

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return self.lower <= value <= self.upper

    def __call__(self, h=_h):
        yield from dense_range(self.lower, self.upper, h)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Interval [{self.lower}, {self.upper}]>"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like it'd make a lot more sense to have an `endpoints` tuple and do `a, b = I.endpoints`.

Comment: `a, b = *I` wouldn't be valid Python syntax.

Comment: Totally agree with that, but in does terms I would like to make the `*` unpacking that tuple.

Comment: @ddejohn so there is no datamodel method that allows me this?

Comment: Unpacking a tuple is just `a, b = I`. I believe you'd just need to implement `__next__`.

Comment: Correct, because that syntax is not part of Python's grammar.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think you also need `__next__`, correct?

Comment: @ddejohn: Usually you'd just implement `__iter__`, not `__next__` (`Interval` doesn't seem to be a logical iterator, but it's iterable). You either implement `__iter__` as the identity method (does nothing but `return self`) and provide a "real" `__next__` (making a single-use iterator which seems inappropriate here), or implement only `__iter__` (often easiest to do so as a generator function) without `__next__`, making a reusable iterable (something that can be used to make iterators).

Comment: As for `**`, I'm unclear on what you'd expect it to do if you used `**` (I see no logical names it would unpack to).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ShadowRanger, any feedback for my answer? This isn't an area I mess around with too often in Python.

Comment: @ddejohn, I'm not sure I'm trying this...

I feel this is related, I'm looking deep in to it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402220/custom-double-star-operator-for-a-class

Comment: I just tried implementing `**` for this, and it looks like you can't have your cake and eat it too. `__iter__()` needs to return the keys, not the values, so that makes `*` unpacking not work for your purpose. [Here's a minimal gist.](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/84457dcc1849aa23744359afff0720c0)

Comment: @wjandrea: You can make it work if `__iter__` and `keys` are implemented independently (with `__iter__` producing values, and `keys` producing the keys); `**` unpacking for stuff that isn't a subclass of `dict` is implemented by iterating over the result of the `keys` method and looking up each key (via `__getitem__`). That said, the resulting instances are not intuitive (normal mappings *should* iterate over their keys), so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah, thanks! I think I missed that because [`Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) has a `keys` mixin that uses `__iter__`, though I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L828) and I don't see how exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a lot of experience implementing iterators, but I believe all you need is to yield the relevant items from `__iter__`:

```py
class Interval:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        if a >= b:
            raise Exception("Invalid values for an interval")
        self.upper = b
        self.lower = a

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return self.lower <= value <= self.upper

    def __call__(self, h=_h):
        yield from dense_range(self.lower, self.upper, h)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.lower
        yield self.upper

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Interval [{self.lower}, {self.upper}]>"
```

Some uses:

```py
In [5]: interval = Interval(1, 7)

In [6]: a, b = interval

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 1

In [8]: b
Out[8]: 7

In [9]: [*interval]
Out[9]: [1, 7]

In [10]: [value for value in interval]
Out[10]: [1, 7]

In [11]: dict(zip("ab", interval))
Out[11]: {'a': 1, 'b': 7}

In [12]: a, b, *c = interval

In [13]: a
Out[13]: 1

In [14]: b
Out[14]: 7

In [15]: c
Out[15]: []

In [16]: a, *b, c = interval

In [17]: a
Out[17]: 1

In [18]: b
Out[18]: []

In [19]: c
Out[19]: 7
```

Comment: This breaks the iteration functionality the questioner also wanted, though. It's not possible to separate the behavior of iterable unpacking and iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. What functionality does OP want that this doesn't support?

Comment: They want `for x in I` to produce different elements from `*I`.

Comment: Note the requirement in the question, "Iterate over it, by calling with an specific step, or just using a default step, hence the `__call__`, and `__iter__`."

Comment: Ah does this interfere with `__call__`? I don't have access to whatever `dense_range` and `_h` are.

Comment: It doesn't interfere with `__call__`, and if the questioner uses `for x in I()`, they'll still get the behavior they wanted. However, they wanted `for x in I` to behave the same as `for x in I()`, hence their `__iter__` method that does `return self()`.

Comment: Fair enough. FWIW I agree with your original comment that an `endpoints` attribute is much more appropriate, but I'll let OP decide if the syntactical tradeoff is worth it to them.

Comment: @ddejohn dense range is a generator from (a, b, step).

Comment: Yes, I figured as much. What this all boils down to is: you can't have it all :)

Comment: I'm trying to write a module for math calculation, and the whole idea of having `__call__` and `__iter__` having somewhat the same behavior is that the _user_ is able to do `I = Interval(1,2)` then `for t in I: ...` or `for t in Interval(1,2)`. (BTW, `_h` is the default step used to iterate or integrate).